# PHP: Remove 'WWW' from URL inside a String

Tags: php, string, dns, parse-url

Currently I am using parse_url, however the host item of the array also includes the 'WWW' part which I do not want. How would I go about removing this?

```
$parse = parse_url($url);
print_r($parse);
$url = $parse['host'] . $parse['path'];
echo $url;
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
$url = preg_replace('#^www\.(.+\.)#i', '$1', $parse['host']) . $parse['path'];
```

This won't remove the `www` in `www.com`, but `www.www.com` results in `www.com`.

Comment: your solution is good, but it miss the case like www.www.test.com. updated version - preg_replace('#^(?:www\.)+(.+\.)#i', '$1', $domain);

Answer (score 11):

```
preg_replace('#^(http(s)?://)?w{3}\.#', '$1', $url);
```

if you don't need a protocol prefix, leave the second parameter empty

Comment: new version:
preg_replace('#^(http(s)?://)?w{3}\.(\w+\.\w+)#', '$1$3', $url); Remove $1 for skipping protocol

Answer (score 6):

```
$url = preg_replace('/^www\./i', '', $parse['host']) . $parse['path'];
```