# PHP Preg Replace - How to remove a URL protocol, the standard www sub-domain while keeping any other non standard www sub-domain?

Tags: php, regex

The Main focus: Remove the protocol and subdomain, but any other non-www subdomain must remain.

**Example 1.** If the protocol and the standard www subdomain such as http://www.example.net, then the expected result must be: *example.net*

**Example 2.** If the protocol and any other non-standard subdomain such as https://jokes.example.net, then the result must be: *jokes.example.net*

Please, any suggestions.

Comment: Why use preg replace? Maybe str_replace will work?

Comment: Please provide sample code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336281/php-remove-www-from-url-inside-a-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549866/php-regex-to-remove-http-from-string I think this is answered too many times. :)

Comment: The main focus of this question is not to just removing the www from the URL.  After reviewing the suggest links they were all unable to answer or address my question and derived any expected results.  However, I have edited the question and hope it will clarify this topic.

Comment: What about `example.co.uk` and `www.example.co.uk`?

Comment: That's not a valid URL.  Try adding "http://" and any of the two answers below should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
$urls="http://www.example.net";
$urls = preg_replace('/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*)\/?$/i', '$1', $urls);
echo $urls; // example.net

$urls="https://jokes.example.net";
$urls = preg_replace('/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*)\/?$/i', '$1', $urls);
echo $urls; // jokes.example.net
```

Comment: How can I use one stone to kill two birds?  I have many url's passing through.  I don't need to maintain a list of the urls.

Comment: pattern is same I only give diiefrent example as your need

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I am looking for.  Just finish testing the code and it works as expected.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace` to check where www is there in url or not.

```
$url = "https://jokes.example.net/";
$parse = parse_url($url);
$res = $url = preg_replace('#^www\.(.+\.)#i', '$1', $parse['host']);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: This code also works as expected.  I totally overlooked parsing the URL, so it's good to see another option.  The code below by B. Desai was the closest to my code and I was able to quickly fix it.  Thanks for understanding the question from the "get go", that tells me you are also a pro.