# Removing "www." from search query

Tags: php, laravel, url

Currently I'm removing `https://` and `http://` with following code:

```
$r=\Input::get('searchQuery');
        
        $Query = preg_replace( "#^[^:/.]*[:/]+#i", "", $r);
        $Query=rtrim($Query, "/");
```

I need to remove `www.` as well. What should I add to the code inorder to remove `www.`

Eg: When I search for `https://www.example.com/` It should only search for `example.com`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027102/get-domain-name-from-full-url   @stanev01 answer

Comment: you can simply do separate if the string is either `https://www.example.com/` or `http://www.example.com/`, use `Str::of($str)->after('https://www.');}` see here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-fluent-str-after

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get domain name from full URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027102/get-domain-name-from-full-url)

Comment: Are you just wanting the www. removing or does it also need to remove other subdomains? i.e. `www.example.com` becomes `example.com`, should `sub1.example.com` remain the same or become `example.com`

Comment: Did none of all the answers help you ?

Comment: Could you please check it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336281/php-remove-www-from-url-inside-a-string

Comment: @nortonvuv Are you alive ? Did any of our answers help ?

Answer (score 3):

It is really easy, you can use `preg_replace` with a simple regex:

```php
$query = preg_replace('/^((http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(www\.)?)/i', '', $text);
```

See [this example](https://regex101.com/r/n4Val3/1), so you can understand my regex.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex works on any string with an optional "http(s)", "www." and trailing slash:

```
$r=\Input::get('searchQuery');
$Query = preg_replace('/^(https?\:\/\/)?(www.)?|\/$/', "", $r);
```

**How it works**:

`^` start of the string.

`(https?\:\/\/)?` optionally match "http(s)://" (the "s" is also optional).

`(www.)?` optionally match: "www.".

`|\/$` match "/" if it is the last character of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel Helpers Method [preg_replace_array](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-preg-replace-array). `preg_replace_array` function replaces a given pattern in the string sequentially useing an array:

```
$string = 'https://www.example.com/'
$query = preg_replace_array('#^[^:/.]*[:/www.?]+#i', [''], $string); // example.com/
$query = rtrim($query, '/'); // example.com
```

Input: `https://www.example.com/` 
Output: `example.com`

Answer (score 0):

```
$r=\Input::get('searchQuery');
$query = preg_replace_array('#^[^:/.]*[:/www.?]+#i', [''], $r);  
$query = rtrim($query, '/'); // google.com
```

**Your OUT PUT will be  `google.com`**

I hope You Got Your Solution .

Answer (score 0):

code might get bit long but this works everytime, you can add more fuctionality by getting position of / inside of string ,  working code as below

```
 <?php
       // $r=\Input::get('searchQuery');
       // $searchQuery = $r; 

       $searchQuery = "www.google.com";

        $searchQuery = str_replace("https://","",$searchQuery);
        $searchQuery = str_replace("http://","",$searchQuery);
      $searchQuery = str_replace("www.","",$searchQuery);
            ?>
<?php #to remove only last / from string
         $lastchar = substr($searchQuery , -1);
    $length = strlen($searchQuery);

    if ($lastchar == "/")
    {
    $searchQuery  = substr_replace($searchQuery, "" , -1);
    }
    else {
    $searchQuery  = $searchQuery ;
    }
    echo $searchQuery; ?>
```